# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'exceptions'

Tags: python-3.x, post, exceção, python-requests

Estou tentando usar o módulo requests com python porém estou tendo os seguintes erros:

```
File "/home/santana/string.py", line 35, in <module>
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'exceptions'
```

Já instalei o módulo requests no python3.6 e python2.7 usando

```
pip3  install requests
pip2  install requests
```

e também

```
sudo pip3 install requests --upgrade
```

porém em todas as alternativas tenho recebido o mesmo erro.

tentei forçar o import usando `"from requests import exception"` porém o erro muda para:

```
  File "/home/santana/string.py", line 34, in <module>
  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'post'
```

O que me faz duvidar se a instalação do módulo foi feita corretamente. Alguém pode me dizer se o problema está na instalação do módulo ou no código?

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import requests
import random
from requests import exceptions

string_api_url = "http://string-db.org/api"
output_format = "tsv-no-header"
method = "get_string_ids"

## contruct params dictionary

### URL FORMAT ###
#https://string-db.org/api/[output-format]/get_string_ids?identifiers=[your_identifiers]&[optional_parameters]

params = {

    "identifiers" : "\r".join(["p53", "BRCA1", "cdk2", "Q99835"]), # your protein list
    "species" : 9606, # species NCBI identifier
    "limit" : 1, # only one (best) identifier per input protein
    "echo_query" : 1, # see your input identifiers in the output
    "caller_identity" : "www.awesome_app.org" # your app name

}

## contruct method URL

request_url = string_api_url + "/" + output_format + "/" + method

## Call STRING

try:

    response = requests.post(request_url, params=params)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print(e)
    sys.exit()

## Read and parse the results

c = 0
for line in response.text.strip().split("\n"):
    l = line.split("\t")
    print(l)
    input_identifier, string_identifier = l[0], l[2]
    print("Input:", input_identifier, "STRING:", string_identifier, sep="\t")
```

Comment: Deve ser um erro no seu environment, com certeza. No meu computador (Python 3.7.3, x64 e requests 2.21.0) funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Se fez `from requests import exceptions`, por que não utiliza apenas `exceptions.RequestException`?

Comment: E se está utilizando o Python 3, não há motivos para fazer `from __future__ import print_function`. Por acaso você copiou esse código de algum lugar?

Comment: Código [rodando no Python 3](https://sopt-question-382324-python3.acwoss.repl.run) e [rodando no Python 2](https://sopt-question-382324-python2.acwoss.repl.run), o que torna sua pergunta não reproduzível. Busque editá-la e adicionar mais detalhes do problema, de preferência criando um [mcve].

Comment: Anderson Carlos, primeiramente desculpa pela pergunta não reproduzivel.
Eu falei sobre as versões porque eu tentei usar nas duas, porém os erros foram os mesmos. 
Sobre o exceptions.RequestException, eu estou utilizando assim mesmo e o erro não ocorreu mais, porém agora estou obtendo um erro novo assim como eu comentei. 
Sobre o from __future__ import print_function eu utilizei porque como eu disse tentei em versões diferentes do python, não só a 3 versão. 
Esse código eu obtive na plataforma string-db, segue o link https://string-db.org/cgi/help.pl?sessionId=lb0oZGkX9I3j&subpage=api

Answer (score 2):

Você deve ter um arquivo, na sua pasta de trabalho, chamado "requests.py" - o Python está achando esse e tentando importa-lo, em vez da biblioteca `requests` instalada com o PIP.

A solução é renomear o seu arquivo para outra coisa qualquer.